# Making OpenLayers.Control.DragPan persist?

Tags: openlayers-2, pan

I want to use controls like DrawFeature and SelectFeature, but while these controls are active, I want to have a way to drag the map, using DragPan control.

For example, I am selecting features. I select then first, the I would have to pan the map in order to select the 2nd feature (not unselecting the 1st one).

Is it possible to make DragPan work as some kind of background control, that would always be active, even when using other controls?

Answer (score 1):

From:
http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SelectFeatureControlMapDragIssues

try setting stopDown = false on the SelectFeature.

That is,

```
selectFeatureControl.handlers.feature.stopDown = false; // for OL2.7
```

OR

```
selectFeatureControl.handler.stopDown = false; // for OL < 2.7
selectFeatureControl.handler.stopUp = false;
```